# No inheritance found with operator= and initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, operator-overloading

Here the code that I a lot simplify for this question.

```
template<class T>
class A
{
public:

    A<T>& operator=(A<T> const& other)
    {
        std::cout << "A<T>& operator=(A<T> const& other)\n";
        return this->operator=(other.m_container);
    }

    template<class U>
    A<T>& operator=(std::vector<U> const& other)
    {
        std::cout << "A<T>& operator=(std::vector<U> const& other)\n";
        // Code not shown: m_container = other;
        return *this;
    }

    A<T>& operator=(std::initializer_list<T> il)
    {
        std::cout << "A<T>& operator=(std::initializer_list<T> il)\n";
        // Code not shown: m_container = il;
        return *this;
    }

    std::vector<T> m_container;
};

//
template<typename T>
class B: public A<T>
{};
```

Initially I believed it was an issue with template but this does not change facts.
So here the simplified classes for my question:

```
class AA
{
public:

    AA& operator=(AA const& other)
    {
        std::cout << "AA& operator=(AA const& other)\n";
        return this->operator=(other.m_container);
    }

    AA& operator=(std::vector<float> const& other)
    {
        std::cout << "AA& operator=(std::vector<float> const& other)\n";
        // Code not shown: m_container = other;
        return *this;
    }

    AA& operator=(std::initializer_list<float> il)
    {
        std::cout << "AA& operator=(std::initializer_list<float> il)\n";
        // Code not shown: m_container = il;
        return *this;
    }

    std::vector<float> m_container;
};

//
class BB: public AA
{};
```

My question is that I'm not totally sure to understand why:

```
BB bb1;
bb1 = { -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f };
```

is not compiling:

```
In function ‘int main()’:
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘BB’ and ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’)
     bb1 = { -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f };
                                ^
note: candidate: ‘BB& BB::operator=(const BB&)’
     BB& operator=(BB const& other)
         ^~~~~~~~
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘const BB&’
```

While the following modification, the code is working:

```
class BB: public AA
{
public:

    BB& operator=(std::initializer_list<float> il)
    {
        std::cout << "BB& operator=(std::initializer_list<float> il)\n";
        AA::operator=(il);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Result:

```
BB& operator=(std::initializer_list<float> il)
AA& operator=(std::initializer_list<float> il)
```

This is particularly strange because the following code is not impacted (the inheritance is well called):

```
BB bb1;
BB bb2;
bb2 = bb1;
```

Result:

```
AA& operator=(AA const& other)
AA& operator=(std::vector<float> const& other)
```

So no need to change the class to:

```
class BB: public AA
{
public:

    BB& operator=(BB const& other)
    {
        std::cout << "BB& operator=(BB const& other)\n";
        AA::operator=(other.m_container);
        return *this;
    }

    BB& operator=(std::initializer_list<float> il)
    {
        std::cout << "BB& operator=(std::initializer_list<float> il)\n";
        AA::operator=(il);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

At first, I thought it was because I had to call `base<T>::method()` from a template derived class that was why I had to create a `derived<T>::method()` calling the base but this is not the reason. Ideally I would like avoiding creating `BB& operator=(std::initializer_list<float> il)` that looks like a useless copy/past code to me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make it into a converting constructor instead: `AA(std::initializer_list<float> il)` and do `using AA::AA;` in  `BB`

Comment: The statement `BB bb1 = { -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f };` is not what is failing with the error you show, since it's *initialization* (which calls a constructor) and not assignment. Please [edit] your question to include a proper [mcve] to show us.

Comment: Thanks Some programmer dude, I fixed my answer. Sorry I gave a try while writing this question and forget to restore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is when you try something as

```
BB bb1;

bb1 = { -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f };
```

not when you try to initialize your `BB` object with an initializer list. The error is coming from `operator=()`.

To solve your problem, I suggest that you add a `using`, in your `BB` class, as follows

```
class BB: public AA
 {
   public:
      using AA::operator=;
 };
```

The problem is that `BB` implicitly define a couple of `operator=()` (the copy and the move `operator=()`: `BB & BB::operator= (BB const &)` and `BB & BB::operator= (BB &&)` respectively) that hide the operators inherited from `AA`.

To un-hide them, you have to explicitly bring them into scope with a `using` declaration.

Comment: Compiler-generated functions hiding inherited functions is one of the most confusing corners of C++.

Comment: @MarkRansom - I'm agree. Combined the combinations related to default constructors/destructor/operator=(), become a true nightmare.